# Reading the csv file in C# and add row at the latest

Tags: c#, csv, opencsv, read.csv

I am new in c# programming. For my current project I am using c# for a 2D Barcode Reader where barcode value is being stored in a csv file. I have added different columns to store my Barcode value decoded into "Fasterner_type", "volume", "production_date", "batch_number", "customer_id". But right now I am struggling to store my Barcode Reader value in new rows. Everytime Barcode scans and it stores the values in first row of the csv file. I want to store my value in the last newest row. For that case I tried to read the csv file line by line and stroing the values in lat row. But it didn't work. Here is my code. I have been stucking so any suggestion or help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CsvHelper;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;
using CsvReader = CsvHelper.CsvReader;

namespace BarcodeCsv2
{
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600);
        try
        {
            
            mySerialPort.Open(); //open the serial port               
                         
           
            Console.WriteLine("Incoming Data");              
           

            while (true) // loop indefinitely
            {
                if (mySerialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    //byte b = (byte)mySerialPort.ReadByte();
                    //char c = (char)mySerialPort.ReadChar();

                    //string line = mySerialPort.ReadLine();
                    //string all = mySerialPort.ReadExisting();
                    string all = mySerialPort.ReadExisting();

                    string[] subs = all.Split('/');

                    string Fastner_Type = subs[0];
                    string volume = subs[1];
                    string production_date = subs[2];
                    string batch_number = subs[3];
                    string customer_id = subs[4];

                    //Console.WriteLine(subs[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine("fastner_type: " + Fastner_Type);
                    Console.WriteLine("volume: " + subs[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine("production_date: " + subs[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine("batch_number: " + subs[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine("customer_id: " + subs[4]);




                    var testlist = new List<TestDataModel1>();

                    testlist.Add(new TestDataModel1() { Fasterner_type = Fastner_Type, volume = volume, production_date = production_date, batch_number = batch_number, customer_id = customer_id });



                    string filename = "C:\\Shakir\\2022\\c# training\\C# training\\Practice\\BarcodeCsv2\\file.csv";

                    string filePath = @"C:\Shakir\2022\c# training\C# training\Practice\BarcodeCsv2\file.csv";



                    StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(filePath);
                    string line;
                    string[] row;
                    readFile.ReadLine();
                    while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        row = line.Split('/');
                        Fastner_Type = row[0];
                        volume = row[1];
                        production_date = row[2];
                        batch_number = row[3];
                        customer_id = row[4];

                    }
                    readFile.Close();


                    var writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
                    var csvwriter = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    csvwriter.WriteRecords(testlist);

                    

                    csvwriter.Dispose();
                    writer.Dispose();

                    var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Shakir\2022\c# training\C# training\Practice\BarcodeCsv2\file.csv");
                    var csvreader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    var output = csvreader.GetRecords<TestDataModel>();



                }
            }

          
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use a database instead; the sooner you switch to using a correct tool for a task the easier it is to switch

Comment: Side note, I'm sure you don't need two CSV libraries, and check your tags please; the post seems to be C# so the command for reading a CSV in R (a totally different programming language) is misplaced, as is tagging a Java csv library

Comment: Here`s a way to append lint to csv file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701936/append-data-to-a-csv-file-using-c-sharp

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for the suggestion. To correct my code and achieve my goal which part and where should I change?

Comment: Switching over to a DB is perhaps a bit beyond the scope of an SO answer, and certainly beyond the scope of a comment; I would consider looking at a SQLite and EFCore tutorial perhaps, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli - the main idea being you store your data in the DB, you fetch, update and store it, and if you ever want to export it to CSV you do so, but the database is the source of truth, not a CSV file

Comment: Can anyone write me here the correct code to instert row at the end and storing the latest barcode values in the last insterted row. I would be privileged then. Thanks